# onCompleted never gets called

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

By using RxSwift, the purpose of my project is whenever an user types a city in search bar, it will make a call to wrap the current temperature. Currently, I have `viewModel` which contains

```
var searchingTerm = Variable<String>("") // this will be binded to search text from view controller
var result: Observable<Weather>!         // this Observable will emit the result based on searchingTerm above.
```

In api service, I'm wrapping a network call using RxSwift by following

```
func openWeatherMapBy(city: String) -> Observable<Weather> {
    let url =   NSURL(string: resourceURL.forecast.path.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("EnterYourCity", withString: city))

    return Observable<WeatherModel>.create({ observer -> Disposable in
        let downloadTask    =   self.session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let err = error {
                observer.onError(err)
            }
            else {
                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]

                    let weather = Weather(data: json)
                    observer.onNext(weather) 
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
                catch {

                }

            }
        })

        downloadTask.resume()

        return AnonymousDisposable {
            downloadTask.cancel()
        }
    })
}
```

As long as the model created, I'll send it to an observer and complete

At view controller, I'm doing

```
viewModel.result
            .subscribe( onNext:     { [weak self] model  in
                            self?.weatherModel = model
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                                self?.cityLabel.text        = model.cityName
                                self?.temperatureLabel.text = model.cityTemp?.description
                            })

                        },
                        onError:    { (error) in
                            print("Error is \(error)")
                        },
                        onCompleted:{
                            print("Complete")
                        }
                      )
                            { print("Dealloc")}
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
```

It works as expected, UI is updated and show me what I want. However, I have just realized that `onCompleted` never gets called. I assume if I do everything right, I must have it printed out.

Any ideas about this issue. All comments are welcomed here.

Comment: do you send a `complete` signal to your subcriber?

Comment: Please add the code where you map from `Observable<WeatherModel>` to `Observable<Wheather>`

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca: i have just updated my codes. please take a look again.

Comment: @Hoa: i did send a complete to my subscriber though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` seems to be derived from `searchingTerm`, which is a `Variable`.

`Variable` only complete when they are being deallocated ([source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/3c55a309a24fbe3dbc480431798eec072b633b85/RxSwift/Subjects/Variable.swift#L59)) so it makes sense that `result` does not receive `onCompleted`.

It makes sense that the behavior is this one. An observable will never emit new values after `onCompleted`. And you don't want it to stop updating after the first search result is presented.

Comment: thanks. Correct me if I am wrong it means `Variable` only completes when `viewModel` is getting deallocated ?